# HTML5 Javascript SWITCH not running in head or body

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple code written in JS and embedded in the html5 document. Cannot get this thing to run no matter where I place the script part (head or body). I have enabled all content in my browsers but none of them runs the script.

Any ideas where the issue could be?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>tryme</title>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
        var instr = prompt("which instrument do you play?");
        switch(instr) {
            case "violin":
            case "piano":
                alert("Me too!");
                break;
            case "drums":
            case "ukulele":
                alert("sonds good");
                break;
            case "whistle":
                alert("omg!!!");
                break;
            default:    
                alert("whatever...");
        }
      </script>
      <noscript>"your browser doesnt support javascript"</noscript>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your console for errors.. maybe that will give you a clue.\

Comment: What editor do you use to program? Seems you've got unwanted (invisible) characters in your code.

Comment: I copy pased you code and it had funny semicolons.. maybe some weird special chars causing this.. otherwise this seems to work for me.. Classic copy paste issue..

Comment: The semicolon is the invalid token.

Comment: The semicolons in your example are not semicolons, they are `\u037e` characters. Which editor are you using?

Comment: When I copied your code to the notepad it worked when saving it with ANSI encoding. Unicode gave me the same error

Comment: Thanks! I was getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" in chrome. I've used MS Expression web 4 to write this but the editor didn't show any errors...is there a way to prevent these errors? just use different editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your semi-colon looking characters (`;`) are actually [showing up as the unicode](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html):

> U+037E : GREEK QUESTION MARK

Rather than the correct semi-colons (`;`):

> U+003B : SEMICOLON

With the "wrong semi-colon", you see this error in the browser developer console (usually press F12 to open):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

JavaScript supports unicode directly in source files, so you have to be very careful about which characters are used in the source.

Comment: Jesus, I was completely at a loss.

Comment: Thanks - I used MS expression web 4 which didn't show anything...I will use notepad++

Comment: @whada That won't necessarily solve the problem - it's not what software you're using, but what characters you're typing into it.  IE This is probably more related to your keyboard input settings and what characters you have on your keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that your ";" semicolons have the wrong encoding.

Answer (score -1):

This is sample example as like your code. It working fine.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <title>tryme</title>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            var instr = prompt("which instrument do you play?");
            switch(instr){
              case "2":  
              case "1":alert('hello');
              break;
              case "dd":
              case "tt":alert('hello tt');
              break;
              default:alert("no any");
            }
          </script>
          <noscript>"your browser doesnt support javascript"</noscript>
       </body>
    </html>
```